# Async/await / Task.WhenAll() / parallelism (multi-threading)

Tags: multithreading, async-await, parallel-processing, task, threadpool

I have two questions after a discussion with a collegue at work today.

This two questions concerne this portion of code (it is pure fake code, representing the exact structure of the real code in an application) :

```
    public async Task<string> GetSomething(int userId, int addressId)
    {
        var taskA = GetUserAsync(userId);
        var taskB = GetAddressAsync(addressId);

        await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB); //Is Taks.WhenAll does parallelism (multitreading)?

        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(new List<string>()
        {
            taskA.Result,
            taskB.Result
        }); //'.result' is synchrone? Does it block the thread if taskA or taskB encounter some problem and can't finish?
    }
```

My collegue says to me, "WhenAll() give some performence, because it does parallelism". Is it true? I am very surprised by this statement. For me, it does not.

The second question is : If I do a WhenAll(), and after, I call the result by ".result", for me if something goes wrong with one of both task, the ".result" should block the thread?

For me, the right way to do asynch here is :

```
    public async Task<string> GetSomething(int userId, int addressId)
    {
        var resultA = await GetUserAsync(userId);
        var resultB = await  GetAddressAsync(addressId);

        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(new List<string>()
        {
            resultA,
            resultB
        });
    }
```

This version doesn't need WhenAll, and the thread should not be blocked if something goes wrong?

Am I right or wrong. I am a new developper, since 2 years, and I am not confidend with async/await and multithreading.

Thank you !

Comment: AFAIK, no, it does not use any thread. Async benefit from concurrency, not multithreading (unless you adapt the code so to use multiple thread yourself). I guess the confusion comes from a misunderstanding of how async operation works and the [doc itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-7.0). Sentences like "*ensures that all threads have completed*" are pretty confusing. For the rest, consider reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0) part of the doc.

Comment: Incroyable Richard, tu es français et en plus lyonnais comme moi  ^^ Merci beaucoup pour ta réponse. Donc en somme, le WhenAll ne parallelise rien et n'utilise pas de thread, il s'assure juste que les tâches aient aboutit.

Comment: Cependant, pour la seconde question, j'ai bien regardé le lien linké, et merci beaucoup pour ce lien, mais je n'ai pas réussi à avoir ma réponse. Pour moi, le .result est synchrone par définition. Donc si on fait un .result de la tâche, même avec un await WhenAll avant, ça casse l'async non?

Comment: Encore milles merci pour ton aide !!!

Comment: Ha, sacrée coïncidence ^^". Oui, par défaut, pas de multithreading, bien qu'il me semble qu'il est possible de faire son propre thread pool pour exécuter les tâches dans les threads si besoin (pas fait par défaut). `WhenAll` crée une tâche de synchro qui attend les autres. Il n'est pas bloquant en soit sauf si on fait un `Wait` sur la tache résultante. Le fait de faire un `await` à un effet similaire sauf que cela ne bloque pas le thread vu qu'on est dans une fonction async.

Comment: Normalement, récupérer le résultat est bloquant s'il n'est pas prêt, mais ici rien ne devrait bloquer je pense vu qu'on fait un `await Task.WhenAll(...)` avant. Note que plusieurs fonctions async peuvent s'exécuter de manière concurrent de manière à être plus efficace que sans async sans être multithread pour autant. Typiquement, C# execute les fonctions async jusqu'à rencontrer une attente async (eg. reception donnée réseau async) puis switch sur une autre fonction async si possible et débloquera l'await quand c'est possible. Du coup, les codes CPU-bound ne seront pas plus rapide en async.

Comment: Normalement on à un `.Result` que dans des fonctions synchrones et `result = await ...` dans des fonctions asynchrone. Avoir un `.Result` dans une fonction async pourrait causer une attente active bloquant le thread si le code n'est pas bien fait. De ce que je sais, `Result` se base sur le concept de [future/promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) en interne. `.Result` cause donc un get de la valeur future qui fait un wait que si elle n'est pas encore produite ce qui ne pose pas de soucis avec await vu que C# ne schedule la fonction que si la valeur est assurément produite

Comment: Le fonctionnement de C# concernant l'exécution de fonction async/await se base sur de [l'ordonnancement coorpératif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking). PS: note qu'en général on préfère parler en anglais sur StackOverflow même en étant parfois tous Français pour que les future lecteur passant ici (qui ne sont pas forcement Français) puisse avoir aussi de l'aide ;) .

Comment: Franchement, milles merci encore une fois Jérôme ! Et bien noté pour la langue, je ferais cet effort effectivement, pour la communauté :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "WhenAll() give some performence, because it does parallelism". Is it true? I am very surprised by this statement. For me, it does not.

That depends on what you mean by "parallelism". If you just mean "doing multiple things at once", then yes, it's "parallel".

Personally, I only use the term "parallelism" to mean "doing multiple things at once by using multiple threads", in which case I would not say this is parallelism. It is concurrent (doing multiple things at once), but it is asynchronous concurrency, not parallel concurrency. I find value in those specific meanings, but they are not universal.

> The second question is : If I do a WhenAll(), and after, I call the result by ".result", for me if something goes wrong with one of both task, the ".result" should block the thread?

If `WhenAll` completes, then nothing has gome wrong. You would get an exception at the `WhenAll` if either task faulted. If either task didn't complete, then neither would the `WhenAll`. So `.Result` is safe to use. That said, I prefer using `await` because it's more obviously correct and more resilient to future code changes.

Comment: Note that the definition "*doing multiple things at once by using multiple threads*" is quite restrictive for the word "parallelism". For example, instruction-level parallelism (ILP) is a form of parallelism (hence the name) as well as SIMD. Parallelism is relative to the point of view considered. Sequential code accelerated by the ILP are generally not considered as parallel though. For SIMD codes, this is arguable to they they are not parallel. SISD code are the only one class clearly not being parallel. I agree with the rest. It is a good idea to precise such definition for sake of clarity.

Comment: Gentlemen, thank you very much for sharing your knowledge like this! It's a blessing! The subject is complex, and he will ask me for many hours of work before taming it.